# Update some attributes of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in a module included in the User model:

```
module Authentication
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def track_on_login_and_save(request)

    # does NOT work
    update(
      last_login_at: Time.zone.now,
      last_login_ip: request.remote_ip,
      login_count:  login_count + 1
    )

    # WORKS
    self.last_login_at = Time.zone.now
    self.last_login_ip = request.remote_ip
    self.login_count += 1
    save(validate: false)
  end
end
```

I would like not to save the model with `validations: false` so I tried to call the update method but it does not work. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? An unexpected result? Also, do you care about callbacks?

Comment: Check out everything on the right side of this page... http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `update` invokes validation, perhaps the problem is you're calling validation requests. Have you tried this:

```
update_attribute(last_login_at, Time.zone.now)
update_attribute(last_login_ip, request.remote_ip)
update_attribute(login_count,  login_count + 1)
```

Comment: there was indeed a problem with a validation of the virtual attribure password. Adding the if condition to `validates_length_of :password, in: 8..64, if: ->(m) { m.password.present? }` solved the problem (and caused another problem on the password reset form which I solved with a short code in the password_resets controller checking for the presence of password).